# In spring security JSessionids are not cleared after logging out. initially it will loaded before login the page

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using Spring Security. Once I load the login page `jsessionid` is created without logging in. How to clear the session before login?

I have implemented on Spring Security API. In that I am calling as method `config()`.

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/?page=1")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .usernameParameter("ssoId")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .deleteCookies("remember-me")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
        .key("remember-me")
        .tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
        .tokenValiditySeconds(1 * 60 * 60).and().csrf().and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
http
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .maximumSessions(1)
        //.maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true) //added       
        .expiredUrl("/login?sessionExpired")
        .and()
        .invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalidSession");
```

The session needs to cleared properly before login as well as after login. At same time same login page needs to loaded one tab, if I am passing new tab access the same URL is loaded without asking the user credentials its logged in now.

Comment: Why do you want to clear the session before login? Did you save something in your session? After logout the session is cleared, you have nothing to do.

Comment: *At same time same login page needs to loaded one tab, if I am passing new tab access the same URL is loaded without asking the user credentials its logged in now.* The session cookie is shared over all tabs. That's a browser feature.

Comment: I didn't save the session. it will default loaded the session on tomcat app server on web client.

Comment: Then you didn't need to clear the session. The session is empty.